# I'm not able to code this calendar widget in HTML/CSS, can anyone give it a try?

Tags: html, css, calendar, project, tabular

I have been given a small task but I'm not able to complete it any way I try. I was asked to code this calendar widget that I designed in HTML and CSS but I'm not sure of the tables or divs that I'll have to be using!

This is how the calendar is supposed to look like:

[image: Proposed Calendar Widget]

This is how I've designed it for now:

[image]

The live demo of the site can be found here, as well as the code to what I've done: http://trendgfx.com/projects/comet-tavern/

Please help me.

Comment: for best result use tables as you will get each row items in definite place where you want to place...

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava I tried tables in my version, if you checked it out.. it still doesn't place the numbers in a definitive region! :\

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava they are tables already :)

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava did you visit the site and eyeball the source?

Comment: @DanF First time I did see the given link now when you said then I recheck again the question and find the link....Thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get rid of the `float:left` and `display:inline-block` on the `#archive-calender th {` and `#archive-calender td {` you get a lot closer.

Next up you'll want to set `border-collapse` to `separate` on `#archive-calender {` and throw in some `border-spacing:3px` to get the gaps between the cells

Finally, a bit of `padding:2px` on the `#archive-calender td {` will give you some breathing room inside the cells.

HTH

**edit** forgot the background on the cells.

Add either some `background-color` or `background-image` to `#archive-calender td {` and you'll get the nice grey cells.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I needed, thank you so much! :) Funny, I've never heard of the `border-collapse` code. What does that actually do?

Also, is there a way to add the background now using the existing divs and tables? Or will I have to create a new div enclosing them and set the styles?

Comment: I was finally able to add a `background-color` on the `td` styles and a `:hover` attachment to get that orange box on one! :) Thank you so much for your help bro!

Comment: No worries! [Border Collapse on mozilla doco](https://developer-new.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-collapse) explains what it does quite nicely